# Action Chains only working after the program gives an error

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium to go to this [website](https://www.sofascore.com/tournament/football/brazil/brasileiro-serie-a/325), scroll down to the matches widget, and roll all the way down this [widget scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUH62.png) so I can collect some info. If it doesn't scroll down, then my variables collecting data return empty, and when the code goes to grab info from the variables, I get Index Error because the variables are empty.

The thing is, I wrote the following code, and the widget scrollbar only moves down in the driver when the code returns error, meaning it was too late to move the scrollbar. If the scroll was moved at the right time, the code wouldn't even return error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.sofascore.com/tournament/football/brazil/brasileiro-serie-a/325")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1130);")
time.sleep(5)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(bar).click_and_hold().perform()
time.sleep(4)
#after this i just select some data
```

Comment: what data are you after? It's possible there is an api to get that and no need to use Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
actions.move_to_element(bar).click().perform()
a = 0
while a < 15:
    actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys(
        Keys.DOWN)
    a += 1
actions.key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```